# Qt signals and slots with threaded class

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals, slot

I have a QWidget TableView class that displays tables, calculates data etc...

Inside its costructor I start FortuneServer server of the class:

```
FortuneServer::FortuneServer(QObject *parent)
    : QTcpServer(parent)
{
...
```

This class starts a new thread on FortuneServer::incomingConnection that looks like:

```
FortuneThread::FortuneThread(int socketDescriptor, const QString &fortune, QObject     *parent)
: QThread(parent), socketDescriptor(socketDescriptor), text(fortune)
{
}

void FortuneThread::run()
{
    QTcpSocket tcpSocket;
    if (!tcpSocket.setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
        emit error(tcpSocket.error());
        cout<<"socket error"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    tcpSocket.waitForReadyRead(10000);
    // this where sockets opens and waits for incoming data...
```

I need to do the folowing:

1. I need to connect the string I get in this thread from the client, with some function inside TableView class that calculates another string and returnes it back into this thread and send it to the client.
2. If I use emit from the thread, how do I make the thread wait for result?

How is this done correctly?

ty

Answer (score 3):

When reading bytes from a source on the network you can :

1- Use a binary message with a fixed length. So you can wait for blocks of bytes to be read and do whatever you need to do with it.
2- Use a string based protocol which uses delimiters for separating the messages. When a delimiter is seen you need to extract a new income message.
3- Use something like Content Length to know how many bytes have come and you should read.

in Qt, you need to have a `slot` in the **Called** class. As well a `signal` in the **Caller** class. When a new string is arrived(using whatever method) you simply emit the signal and the called classes will get notified. You have to use `connect()` method to connect slot to signal. I think `QIODevice` which is a parent for `QTcpSocket` has a signal named readyRead() which gives you the signal when new data are available.

Never do operations which are probable to throw exceptions in a constructor. It is better to make and start server out of the constructor in a different method.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this would be not to start a separate thread, but rather give your socketDescriptor int to a QSocketNotifier object (of type QSocketNotifier::Read) and connect the QSocketNotifier's activate(int) signal to a slot in your GUI's class.  Then whenever bytes become ready-for-read from the network, your slot will be called in the main thread and you can read them and deal with them there, without having to work about inter-thread messaging or signaling or blocking issues.  Much easier that way :)